# jQuery: how to trigger hover out?

Tags: jquery

How can I trigger second hover function?

```
$('#adm1n-toolbar').hover(
    function() {
        ...
    },
    function() {
        ...
    }
);

$('#adm1n-toolbar-content select').change(function(e) {
    ...
    $('#adm1n-toolbar').trigger('mouseout');
});
```

mouseout or mouseleave does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works just fine if you use `mouseleave` which is what `hover` uses behind the scenes

**demo:**

```js
$('#adm1n-toolbar').hover(
  function() {
    console.log('in');
  },
  function(e) {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast').fadeIn('fast');
  }
);

$('#adm1n-toolbar-content select').change(function(e) {
  $('#adm1n-toolbar').trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adm1n-toolbar">toolbar</div>

<div id="adm1n-toolbar-content">
  <select multiple>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @Radio, most likely... if you have it live somewhere post the link so we can see it in action..

Answer (score 9):

You can't externally target the second function in `hover()`. However as `hover()` is just a shortcut for `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` you can assign them separately to let you trigger them as you need. Try this:

```
$('#adm1n-toolbar')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        // ...
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        // ...
    });

$('#adm1n-toolbar-content select').change(function(e) {
    $('#adm1n-toolbar').trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

Comment: yep... just need to remove extra ) at the end.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: but leave ; =)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli is correct.  You can use `hover()` and still trigger `mouseleave`.  You don't have to explicitly set the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.