# Hover left JQuery, if there is not click on item, set values where they were

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code, I need the when there is not an item clicked and the hover end, the parameters return where they were. for example the border-bottom line and the text color.
if someone can help me, I'll be very thankful....

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#siteloader').load('empleados.jsp');
    $('ul#menu li a.active').css({"border-bottom": "4px solid"});

      $('ul#menu li a').click(function() {
          var page = $(this).attr('href');
          this.setAttribute("id", "lix");
          if (page !== 'index.jsp') {
              $('#siteloader').load(page + '.jsp');
              $('ul#menu li a').css({"color": "#000"});
              $(this).css({"color": "#ca4b00"});

              return false;
          }
          return true;
      });

      $('ul#menu li a').hover(function() {
          $('ul#menu li a').css({"color": "#000"});
          $('ul#menu li a').css({"border-bottom-style": "none"});
          $(this).css({"color": "#ca4b00"});
          $(this).css({"border-bottom": "4px solid"});

      }); 
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseleft, it will work, [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636581/jquery-how-to-trigger-hover-out)

```
$('ul#menu li a').mouseleave(function() {
    // hover end stuuf
});
```

Why dont just use :hover in css?

```
<style>
ul#menu li a:hover {
border-bottom-style: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format of mouse hover and leave:

```
$('ul#menu li a').hover(
    function() {
        //hover
    },
    function(e) {
       //leave
    }
);
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PcvfV/) Uses ToogleClass